# Redirecting to images path via routes.rb in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, routes

I'm writing a Ruby application and using a 3rd party script that loads images.
The images are located at "/images/modern_images/azure/" for example:
"/**images**/modern_images/azure/border.jpg"
The script runs in a page located in the "/events/" path and due to a bug, it tries to access the images in:
"/**events**/modern_images/azure/border.jpg"
The root path is wrong and I can not change the script as it is minified.
How can I do the redirection in routes.rb instead?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify script&  replace 'events' with 'images'. You can make use of `:%s/word/word_to_replace` inside editor.